# maven-deploy-plugin Failed to deploy artifacts: ReasonPhrase: . - No Reasonphrase

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I got a strange error with the maven-deploy-plugin

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project mycomponent: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact nz.co.mycompmany:mycomponent:zip:1.0.35-20180115.210413-4 from/to libs-snapshot-local (https://mycompmany/libs-snapshot-local/): Access denied to: https://mycompmany/libs-snapshot-local/nz/co/mycompmany/mycomponent/1.0.35-SNAPSHOT/mycomponent-1.0.35-20180115.210413-4.zip, ReasonPhrase: . -> [Help 1]
```

So reasonphrase is empty. Normally there would be something like:  ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.

The artifact is in fact uploaded. But when downloading the artifact after the upload somehow it can't:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: https://mycompmany/libs-snapshot-local/nz/co/mycompmany/mycomponant/1.0.35-SNAPSHOT/mycomponant-1.0.35-20180115.210413-4.zip, ReasonPhrase: .
```

So everything seems fine, just maven-deploy-plugin seems to be not happy.

What could that be ?

The error will not happen if I run the command like this:
mvn clean package org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy instead of
mvn clean package deploy

So if I fix it to maven-deploy-plugin version it will not fail.

This seems like a plugin issue.

Comment: Could you run maven command which produces the error with `-e` option and add corresponding stacktrace and error messages to the questions?

Comment: I did run it with -X. The error cause is above, I removed all the surrounding clutter: Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Access denied to: https://mycompmany/libs-snapshot-local/nz/co/mycompmany/mycomponant/1.0.35-SNAPSHOT/mycomponant-1.0.35-20180115.210413-4.zip, ReasonPhrase: .

Answer (score 0):

Access to your `libs-snapshot-local` maven repository is protected (probably by password) and maven doesn't know this password. See [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-deployment-security-settings.html) for details.

Comment: sorry no that is not the problem. The artifact is uploaded correctly. I can actually run the command fine if I fix the maven-deploy plugin to a specific version.

Comment: I've updated the issue above with the details which version of the plugin works fine for me.

Comment: Error happens with version 2.8.2 of the `deploy` plugin, and then you say, that specific invocation of `deploy:deploy` mojo (of the same version 2.8.2) doesn't bring up this error - it looks like version of the plugin is not a problem.

Comment: I know, but still one command works the other doesn't. I think it will have do more then just fixing it to a version of the deploy plugin by supplying the additional parameters. I can repeat the above stable. So it's not temporary working. But fixing it to a specific plugin version (not saying that it's "the" plugin version) seems to fix the issue.